# UISplitViewController not loading its child when launched in compact size

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a problem when launching the app in SplitScreen when the app has compact traits, the `UISplitViewController` is not loading its children unless dragged into regular trait. The view hierarchy is **UITabBarController > UISplitViewController > UINavigationController > UIViewController**.

I made a short video here with the behaviour: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VChb8.jpg . So as you can see unless I drag the window to the regular size, the red view is not loading. I also get this message in the console
`[Assert] Unexpected nil collapsedVC in the panelController`
and my VC's `viewDidLoad` method never gets called unless I drag the window into regular size.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior of split view controllers, they collapse to one controller in a horizontally compact layout. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller?language=objc#3596562):

> The split view controller performs collapse and expand transitions in response to certain changes in its interface. For example, transitions occur when the interface’s size class toggles between horizontally regular and horizontally compact, when a user interaction hides or shows a column, or when you hide or show columns programmatically. The split view controller works with its delegate object to perform collapse and expand transitions. The delegate is an object you provide that adopts the UISplitViewControllerDelegate protocol.

You can control which view controller is shown when it's in the collapsed state:

> In a column-style split view interface, when the interface is collapsed, you can show a different view controller than your primary, supplementary, or secondary. Set the desired view controller for the UISplitViewControllerColumnCompact column using setViewController:forColumn:.

Comment: Well if I resize the view back to the compact size I get the red view, thing that doesn’t happen when I open the app. Also when setting that I want to show the main viewcontroller on top, I get the same result

Comment: @ZR19980119 I'm not sure what you mean by main view controller, I assume that's the controller with the red view? Are you able to share any code samples or a storyboard screenshot of your full view controller hierarchy?

Comment: I just tested now it seems that the UITabBar is the issue...if I just set the SVC as the rootViewController in the window everything works fine, but embedded in the tab bar is not loading correctly. Now wondering how can I fix this

Comment: @ZR19980119 Without knowing your exact layout it's hard to offer help, but one thing you could do is always force the view to load by accessing it programmatically: `let _ = redController.view`